# Github pages work for .html and images, not for .js files (get 404), needs token

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a private repository, with a Jekyll website.

I use the folder `docs` to be my public folder in my github pages settings.

The `index.html` file and images are loaded, but some assets, like .js are not working. For example `/docs/assets/js/_user_variable.js`

When I try to  open the mentioned url in a browser tab, I get a 404 error.
If I go to my repository, and try to look at the raw version of this file, I see the same absolute path in the url bar and the file is loaded, BUT I noticed an additional url parameter like `?token=AAB72EQ74V6CXJ6ZYUJCHWLAPAXV6`

I'm 100% sure this has worked before, but I haven't looked at the website for more then a year. I guess github has changed the requirements for some requests to have a token, but I'm not sure, I couldn't find anything on that.

So it is not necessary to have this token for the `index.html` and the image files, but it is for others files.

I have read https://guides.github.com/features/pages/ and I can not find any thing regarding tokens needed.

I like to access files from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repository_name` without the use of tokens, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you want the raw file (so the browser read it as a text file), you have to have a token:

e.g.:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repository/master/docs/index.html?token=AAB72EUQF7GXPEXY6YZHQHDAPBFOQ`

if you use the following url, it works without token:
`https://username.github.io/repository/assets/js/some_variables.js`

**BUT**

When the file starts with an `_` underscore, this last option will give you an 404.

So don't use underscore, see also: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/55

Comment: Even better, use the relative url so the engine will pick it up correctly, even across domain changes: `/assets/js/some_variables.js`